# Moving tabs within tab in Ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have Tabs within Tabs in my Ionic App. How can I move within the child tabs? This is my hierarchy of

### Tab 1

- Tab A
- Tab B

### Tab 2

### Tab 3

If i am in Tab A (within Tab 1), how can I move to Tab B (which is still under Tab 1)

I tried using $ionicTabsDelegate.select(1) but that moves across the 1st level of tabs
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilise the [`$getByHandle()`](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicTabsDelegate/) method on `$ionicTabsDelegate` passing in your instance of the tab control. For example:

```
$ionicTabsDelegate.$getByHandle('my-handle').select(0);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I was incorrectly setting the handle for the top most tab.. - this works.. Thanks!